# ubuntu \etc\hosts not showing in my ubuntu system

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I modified my `\etc\hosts` file so my localhost points to a specific url `subdomain.mydomain.com`. When i went to the file using `sudo nano \etc\hosts` instead of me seeing content of the file i modified I did not see anything inside the file, it was empty it  looked like the file does not exist at all.

This happened after i restarted the computer.

Please what could be going on and how can i recover the file back.

I am skeptical of creating a new file

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really are using the filename `\etc\hosts` then that's your problem.  `\etc\hosts` with the backslashes is just `etchosts`.  What you want is `/etc/hosts`.